# Flutter Google Play 64-bit requirement on play store

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, google-play

I can't upload the apk's on google play.
I try everything about that. I bored....
I working to this issue about 4 days. 
I try this solutions.

1-)
Add key.properties on android project

```
storePassword=pass
keyPassword=pass
keyAlias=xxxx
storeFile=xxxx.jks
```

Add this lines on build.grandle

```
defaultConfig{
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }


 signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
  buildTypes {
        release {
            if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                println "Signing with key.properties"
            } else {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                println "Signing with debug keys"
            }
        }
    }
```

And i try get apks from android studio. After than i upload the bundle to play store i get some error.
2-)
add this line on build.grandle

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

it's doesn't work too.

3-) I get bundle from flutter CLI on this bash script

```
flutter build appbundle --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

it's again doesnt work.

4-) I get bundle from flutter CLI on this bash script

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

it's again doesnt work.

Flutter --version result is ;

```
Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 20e59316b8 (5 weeks ago) • 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
Engine • revision fee001c93f
Tools • Dart 2.4.0
```

Google play store error is

> This release is not compliant with the google play 64-bit requirement

Comment: What is error message after upload file?

Comment: it is "this release is not compliant with the google play 64-bit requirement"

Comment: Have you tried not specify target platform? In recent version, you don't need to specify anything, but generate 32bit and 64bit by default. At least, my apps are working without warnings.

Comment: Mine doesn't work. I tried everything and i am trying now too...

Answer (score 0):

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {

         signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Here is my configuration and I'm just using `flutter build appbundle` for building the project. Also, don't forget the change version of the project while publishing from pubspec.yaml.